# Arduino SocketIO library not working over HTTPS

Tags: esp8266, adafruit, http

I am currently using this [Socket.io library](https://github.com/washo4evr/Socket.io-v1.x-Library) to be able to send data from the Adafruit Feather HUZZAH (based on ESP8266) to my NodeJS server. It works like a charm on my local webserver, never failing me. However, when I try the setup with the proper webapp hosted on Heroku, the command `SocketIOClient::connect(host, port)` fails and no connection is established with the webserver's SocketIO.

Since there is no mention of limitations with HTTPS connections, I assume that I might be doing something wrong. If the impossibility of having HTTPS connection is the case, however, is there any other way to send this kind of data through web sockets to a NodeJS server hosted on Heroku?

Comment: probably not an arduino question. But it is also hard to know what your doing when you don't post any code or error messages.   "Fails" can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: a lot of tls stuff doesn't work on the 8266 because of lack of power and the shared CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issues with SocketIO and the ESP8266, [this issue](https://github.com/washo4evr/Socket.io-v1.x-Library/issues/55) on Github explains how I solved it:

> When specifying the host, avoid including the `http://` or any other trailing slashes.
>   So it became `String host = "something.herokuapp.com";`